# Optimizing File Operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, redis, filesystems, asynchronous

I've an application in C# which involves a lot of file operations, i.e., reading, moving, deleting, appending, etc. For Example, a file is read from a source path on local FS and after processing, it is deleted from there and the processed file is written to target location on local FS. This is all done parallelly on a group of systems with each working only on the local files. (Files were distributed among them by the load balancer)

How can I possibly improve the performance of this application?

Things that I can think of are:

1.) Create a queue for a particular type of operation such as delete. Put the required info in the queue and a separate thread will be processing the queue.

2.) Instead of working on FS, use a in-memory Data store such as Redis. As the data will be in cache, operations will be faster.

3.) Increasing the parallelism of the code. Each thread will be working on separate file and should be faster.

Will the above approaches work? Please suggest any other alternatives that might be worth giving a thought.

Comment: Unless you have more than one physical hard drive that you're working on, parallelism won't really do you any good.  Telling the drive to do 3 things at once will just involve 2 of those things waiting until the first is done, not 3x speedup.

Comment: @Servy, so you say only one operation can actually happen on a physical hard drive, even though, the operations involve different files altogether.

Comment: @ptntialunrlsd The hard drive only has one head, so yes, it can only be reading/writing to one file at a time, unless you have multiple drives.  That you're manipulating multiple files doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

1.) I would suggest batching together common context operations to reduce sync\context switching overhead and take advantage of the caching mechanism of your processor.

2.) Grouping files together into a single file will reduce windows's handshake per file performance penalty.

3.) Try using of pointer and\or Win32 API that in many cases appears to be faster than their managed wrappers\lib implementations.

4.) Blocking collection queues (Producer consumer) can be a good starting point.